# Writing Device Drivers for AIX...Suggestions

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd, aix

I would like to learn how to write device drivers for IBM AIX OS.
I wanted to know is there any way to do this?

Can I download AIX? any books or docs available on the same?

If not, then if I learn how to write drivers on FreeBSD/Linux will that knowledge help?

Please suggest me..

Thanks a lot in advance.

- Marc

Comment: aix only runs on specialised (power) hardware and requires licenses to download. This would seem like the relevant place to start if you really need to do this, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-device-driver/index.html

Comment: thanks a lot..:-) but if i don't have access to power hardware and i still want to learn based on existing resources like FreeBSD, Linux, does practicing driver writing for these help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing drivers for other platforms like BSD or Linux helps but it also hurts.

AIX has a preemptible, page-able kernel which makes it really weird to write for.  A thread, in a system call, can get preempted.  This is unusual for kernels.  Data structures in the kernel can be paged out.  This is also unusual.  The locking mechanisms are unusual as well.

As you can tell, finding info about AIX is rather hard.  The pubs actually does have most things documented but finding it is rather challenging because IBM and AIX tends to use their own terms.

There is a fairly good book that was published years ago.  You might find it on ebay or something about writing device drivers for AIX.

There are also partner programs that IBM has, google "Partner World", that try to help.

The other thing you will find (especially with the partner programs) is AIX is like the red-headed step child of IBM.  The folks at partner world want to talk about Tivoli, Lotus, DB2, Rational, etc. and few will know much / anything about AIX.  But they do have access to equipment, etc.

Its going to be a tough road to climb.  I keep wondering, why you have decided to do this.  The market for AIX driver writers is nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing really useful information about AIX. Your answer is extremely helpful. Understood now that it is long & hard away ahead...

Answer (score 0):

### Anonymous disinterested help (posted as a guest!)

Found this rather obsolete book on AIX 4.1,

http://bio.gsi.de/DOCS/AIX/SC23-2593-00.pdf